# Processing - If statement and ids

Tags: processing

I'm an Italian student and I'm new in programming. I need your help for a school project.

I'm making a blob tracking program using Daniel Shiffman's tutorials. Currently I have 2 blobs on the screen. I am identifying them with 2 IDs: number `0` and number `1`.

I need to put some conditions on those blobs: if one blob is in a certain part of the screen and the other one is in another part, I need to call a function.

I don't know how to put the `if` conditions separately for the two ids. Below is some pseudo code of what I would like to achieve:

```java
for (id==0)
if (...) and
for (id==1)
if(...) then {
  void()
}
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't understand, you want the if statement to have 2 conditions?

Comment: i need to put conditions on a specific object (named with an ID) @Pepe

Comment: How can i refer to a specific ID when i write mi If statements?@Pepe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know where you want the blobs to be when the desired function fires, but I can try to give you an example...

1. **Blob**

Assign some sort of position variable, in this case PVector, to your blob object.

```java
class Blob {
    PVector position;

    Blob (PVector position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    void update() {
        *random movements, etc...*
    }
}
```

2. **Create two blob objects**

Create two objects and assign a position to each of them.

```java
Blob[] blobs = new Blob[2];

void setup() {
    size(400, 400);

    blobs[0] = new Blob(5, new PVector(40, 40));
    blobs[1] = new Blob(13, new PVector(100, 100));
}
```

3. **Check if blobs is at left or right side of the screen**

I check if blob[0] is at the left side of the screen and if blob[1] is at right side of the screen. If they are, at the same time, the **desiredFunction();** will fire.

```java
void draw() {
    for (int i = 0; i < blobs.length; i++) {
        blobs.update();
    }

    if (blobs[0].position.x < (width / 2) && blobs[1].position.x < (width / 2) {
        desiredFunction();
    }
}
```

4. **Remember**

This is just an example. You could of course check other parts of the screen instead of the left and right parts. You can also use IDs on your blobs instead of an array, I just thought it was better to just use an array in this case.

PS: *I wrote this answer without having processing started. The code has certainly a couple of typing errors.*

Comment: Thank you so much @Warcaith you have been so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

For the example you have described, you can achieve this using the `&&` operator in one `if` statement.

First assign the conditions you want to test to `boolean` variables. For example, create the `boolean` variables `id0IsThere`, and `id1IsThere`, and set them to `true` if the blobs are in the locations you want them to be in. Then use the following `if` statement:

```
if (id0IsThere && id1IsThere) {
  yourFunction();
}
```

The `&&` operator means that the code inside the `if` statement that executes `yourFunction()` is only executed if both conditions are true. In this case, if both blobs are in the positions you want them to be in. Hope that helps. Read more about `if` statements and the `&&` operator here:

- https://processing.org/reference/if.html
- https://processing.org/reference/logicalAND.html

Comment: Thank you @Chris Hamilton , this is exactly what i want to do... I tried to write this simple code :                                                                               boolean a = false;
if    ((id==0)&&(xCenter>150 && xCenter<190) &&
   (yCenter>110 && yCenter<150)) 
 {a=true;} 

boolean b =false;
if    ((id==1)&&(xCenter>480 && xCenter<520) &&
   (yCenter>280 && yCenter<320)) 
 {a=true;} 
if ((a == true)&&(b == true)) {println("great!");}